# UITableViewCell subclass layout in edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm seeing some very strange behaviour in the layout of my custom cell when tableView enters **edit mode**.

It seems like the content view becomes very tiny and is moved to the right of the cell.

[image: example image]
Here's the cells in normal mode to the left and in edit mode to the right.

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

EDIT:

Code for a very simplified version of this issue can be fetched from dropbox [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2717797/CellIssue.zip)

Comment: You can create demo project with this stuff and provide here via dropbox or drive, so anyone can look into it and give a solution.

Comment: How would we know what's happening if you don't show us the code or the layout ?

Comment: @Hasya: Added some code via dropbox

Comment: Is there any reason of not using storyboard and  custom cell itself in table ?

Comment: Using a storyboard is nice for an app with just a couple of views and if you are alone in a project but when working with git in an app with 10+ pages the storyboard just become a nightmare to deal with. Working with separate ViewController code is much easier. The custom cells in separate nibs are necessary because they are reused in other controllers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited after comments* :

Try commenting out below line.

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

[From Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW2)

When a Row is Relocated...

> ... The delegate assigns the controls in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: by setting the showsReorderControl property of UITableViewCell objects to YES

Because you are setting the layoutmargins again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it could be overriding the formed accessory view and redrawing the cell layout.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the accessory views that they just shrink the cell making the auto layout perform just as if the screen were smaller?
I also have a "rigid" layout constraint on the right side but that doesn't screw up the cell when other accessory views are shown on the right side.

Comment: @Moriya makes sense. But the console messages and the above  fix lead me to this. I just commented out                 //cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
in your code it seems to do the trick

Comment: Well... there we have it. For some reason changing the margins screws with auto layout then. You should update your answer and I'll give you the bounty for finding that.

Comment: @Moriya sure thing :)

Comment: have to wait 18 more hours to award it though.

Answer (score -1):

Moriya, I have just gone through your code. I suggest few things as below.
- Use storyboard
- Use customcell itself in table view

It seems like there is problem of autolayout, so using storyboard and customcell within table will help to figure out quickly as everything is within a scene.

I have created separate code, you can [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaDVKMzZfWmVhQ00/view?usp=sharing) from here.

[image]

[image]